# Custom CSS in Wordpress messing up

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm managing the website of my company which is based on Wordpress and I try to figure out how to change my contact page.

I've made a codepen of what I want to do : http://codepen.io/EzhnoFR/pen/PNmdxm

html :

```
  <img class="top" src="http://www.alabama-pub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Isa.png" />
      <span>Hover</span>

</div>

        <div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://www.alabama-pub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/christine-chute.png" />
  <img class="top" src="http://www.alabama-pub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/christine-1.png" />
  <span> Hover </span>
</div>

        <div id="cf">
  <img class="bottom" src="http://www.alabama-pub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/cecile-chute.png" />
  <img class="top" src="http://www.alabama-pub.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/cecile.png" />
  <span> Hover </span>
</div>
    </div>
```

css :

```
#cf img.top {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
    filter: grayscale(80%);
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

span{
  position: absolute;
    bottom: -150px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    width: 225px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: .7s ease-in-out;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

#cf img.top:hover ~ span{
  opacity: 1;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
.column {
    margin: 15px 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.column:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 90px;
}
.column::after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.column div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 0 0 50px;
    padding: 0;
}
.column div:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

However, when I add this html to my page and the css in my wordpress custom css, it all mess up as you can see : http://www.alabama-pub.com/contact-new-test/

I've tried a lot of things but I can't get to fix it, does anyone has any idea ?

Comment: you have extra br under image tag. Remove that.

Comment: @Leothelion On the page ?

Comment: On this page http://www.alabama-pub.com/contact-new-test/ under <div id = cf> then under image.

Comment: I have added image with proper line of code. Check that.

Comment: @Leothelion Thank you, it indeed helped. However, I still can't see the text appearing, have any suggestion ?

Comment: Ohh so you needed hover too. One min.

Comment: @Leothelion Understood, thank you

Comment: in codepan  you have hover text in span tag and css for that. Add that css and span tag in site and you are done.

Comment: If my answer helps you then kindly accept as answer. Thank you

Comment: @Leothelion I've already copied and pasted the full css of the codepen in my wordpress.

Comment: While copying the code in cms, be careful with similar name which is already in used as it will overwrite the css on them. Add span tag to hover text and update so i can check. Thank you

Comment: @Leothelion I added the span tag to the "hover" in the wordpress page.

Comment: please remove z-index from span tag and you are done :)

Comment: @Leothelion Thank you very much ! Appreciated your help, can you explain me why this z-index was messing up the hover text ?

Comment: Z-index will hide that text under the background. In fiddle you might not have that and text was hiding behind white background. Also you don't need padding-bottom:90px in .column:last-child(parent div) and make bottom:-62px in span tag of hover text. Try that :)

Comment: @Leothelion Yes I knew for the bottom :) Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114811/discussion-between-leo-the-lion-and-ezhno).

Comment: i have one more point.

Comment: @Leothelion Yes ? I have a question too ^^'

Comment: Come to chat please to avoid too much msg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra  < br >  under image tag which is causing the issue of height changes on hover.

According to other issue please remove `z-index` from span tag and you are done :)

see [image: Here]